# Using the Python C API, how can I write a function that accepts any number of arguments, including none at all?

Tags: python-c-api

`METH_VARARGS` requires at least one argument; `METH_NOARGS` doesn't seem to let me pass any at all.

How can I define a function `build()` that can be called as either `build()` or `build(True)`/`build(False)`?

Calling a `METH_VARARGS` function with no arguments results in:

```
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking about the problem wrong. It's not the definition, but rather the parsing that rose my TypeError.

To prevent it, I just had to use `"|O"` instead of `"O"` in `PyArg_ParseTuple`!